# Stripe Charge create migration

Tags: python, stripe-payments

i have this python code inside my application:

```
stripe.api_key = "sk_test_xxxxx"
out = stripe.Charge.create(
  amount=1000,
  currency="eur",
  source="acct_yyyyyy",
)
```

and watching Stripe documentation [HERE](https://docs.stripe.com/api/charges/create#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20chargeDeprecated&text=This%20method%20is%20no%20longer,object%20used%20to%20request%20payment.) is flagged as deprecated.
Stripe advise customers migrating to [payment_intents](https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_intents).

My problem is that i can't find a solution using payment_intents that allows me to charge a connected account using his stripe balace.

Any solutions? Thank you in advance.

I tried using [payment_intents](https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_intents) but i can't find a real solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine to use the Charges API for that *specific use case* (an Account Debit). That's still the documented/supported flow:
https://docs.stripe.com/connect/account-debits#charging-a-connected-account

All other use cases for creating Charge objects directly through that API(for charging end-customers) are deprecated yes.

Comment: Thanks for yours helpful informations!